# Get Timestamp rtp packet

Tags: c#, timestamp, rtp

I'm using PacketDotNet to retrieve data from RTP header. But there are times when the timestamp is a negative value.

```
GetTimeStamp(UdpPacket packetUdp)
{

        byte[] packet = packetUdp.PayloadData;
        long timestamp =  GetRTPHeaderValue(packet, 32, 63);
        return timestamp;

}

private static int GetRTPHeaderValue(byte[] packet, int startBit, int endBit)
    {
        int result = 0;

        // Number of bits in value
        int length = endBit - startBit + 1;

        // Values in RTP header are big endian, so need to do these conversions
        for (int i = startBit; i <= endBit; i++)
        {
            int byteIndex = i / 8;
            int bitShift = 7 - (i % 8);
            result += ((packet[byteIndex] >> bitShift) & 1) *
                      (int)Math.Pow(2, length - i + startBit - 1);
        }
       return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by the RTCP packets. If the RTP data is coming from a phone, then phone send periodic RTCP reports. They seem to pop in about every 200'th packet. The format is different and your code is probably reading it the same way - you will need to handle the RTCP packets.

The packets format: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jac22/books/mm/book/node162.html

Comment: HI @Conrad-de-Wet this case the problem was that I was in the variable result as integer, to switch to "long" type the problem has been resolved :)